# Why do Knight Rider and Battlestar Gallactica have similar red lights?

Tags: tv, battlestar-galactica, knight-rider

Coincidence?

[image: KITT]

[image: Cylon]

Or did [Glen A. Larson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glen_A._Larson) just really like the cool effect?

Comment: Clearly, KITT is a Cylon scout in disguise.

Comment: It is a cool effect. I did electronics at school about 25 years ago and it was one of the first things I tried :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KITT#About_the_automobile):

> KITT's scanner is similar to that of Cylons from the science fiction
>   series Battlestar Galactica. Glen A. Larson, the creator of both
>   Knight Rider and Battlestar Galactica has stated that the two shows
>   have nothing else in common and to remove any fan speculation, he
>   stated in the Season One Knight Rider DVD audio-comments, that he
>   simply reused the scanning light for KITT because he liked the effect.

Answer (score 1):

In The Second Season Chapter 4 of Knight Rider ("Merchants of Death"), there is a funny scebe between KITT and Michael Knight and two bikers very similar to a scene from Galactica between two bikers and a spacial vehicle in the shape of a motorcycle that can fly and can also travel as a motorcycle (this Galactica scene was set in the Earth). Of course, Glen A. Larson was the creator of both series and the writer of both scenes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Other than an additional minor point of similarity you don't really have anything to add to the existing answer that has a referenced answer.  Please don't post comments as answers; when you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments on posts.  You might want to take the [tour].